# Strange bash behaviour

Tags: bash, ls

So I'm trying to get a list of all the directories i'm currently running a program in, so i can keep track of the numerous jobs i have running at the moment.

When i run the commands individually, they all seem to work, but when i chain them together, something is going wrong... (`ll` is just the regular `ls -l` alias)

```
for pid in `top -n 1 -u will | grep -iP "(programs|to|match)" | awk '{print $1}'`; 
    do 
    ll /proc/$pid/fd | head -n 2 | tail -n 1; 
done
```

[image]

Why is it that when i have the `ll /proc/31353/fd` inside the `for` loop, it cannot access the file, but when i use it normally it works fine?

And piped through `hexdump -C`:

```
$ top -n 1 -u will | 
    grep -iP "(scatci|congen|denprop|swmol3|sword|swedmos|swtrmo)" | 
        awk '{print $1}' | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 28 42 1b 5b 6d 1b 28  42 1b 5b 6d 32 31 33 35  |.(B.[m.(B.[m2135|
00000010  33 0a 1b 28 42 1b 5b 6d  1b 28 42 1b 5b 6d 32 39  |3..(B.[m.(B.[m29|
00000020  33 33 31 0a 1b 28 42 1b  5b 6d 1b 28 42 1b 5b 6d  |331..(B.[m.(B.[m|
00000030  33 30 39 39 36 0a 1b 28  42 1b 5b 6d 1b 28 42 1b  |30996..(B.[m.(B.|
00000040  5b 6d 32 36 37 31 38 0a                           |[m26718.|
00000048
```

Comment: Did you try `ls -l "/proc/$pid/fd"`?

Comment: @anubhava, yup, makes no difference.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Or just no output?

Comment: The error is exactly as in the question; `ls: cannot access ...`

Comment: Can you pipe the output of the last loop through `hexdump -C` and check if there are any unexpected characters in the output? (I would expect them to show up more obviously on the terminal, but you never know).

Comment: Suggestion: Try `ps -fu will` instead of `top`.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Already have, get exactly the same issue - think the issue might be coming from `awk` maybe.

Comment: The problem is most likely that the processes have exited before you can read them which is just a bit of (bad) luck.

Comment: @Wolph Nope. These processes take hours / days to run each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[chepner had the right hunch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335675/strange-bash-behaviour#comment32164041_21335675). The output of `top` is designed for humans, not for parsing. The hexdump shows that top is producing some terminal escape sequences. These escape sequences are part of the first field of the line so the resulting file name is something like `/proc/\e(B\e[m\e(B\e[m21353/pid` instead of `/proc/21353/pid` where `\e` is an escape character.

Use `ps`, `pgrep` or `pidof` instead. Under Linux, you can use the `-C` option to `ps` to match an exact program name (repeat the option to allow multiple names). Use the `-o` option to control the display format.

```
for pid in $(ps -o pid= -C scatci -C congen -C denprop -C swmol3 -C sword -C swedmos -C swtrmo); do 
  ls -l /proc/$pid/fd | head -n 2 | tail -n 1
done
```

If you want to sort by decreasing CPU usage:

```
for pid in $(ps -o %cpu=,pid= \
                -C scatci -C congen -C denprop -C swmol3 -C sword -C swedmos -C swtrmo |
             sort -k 1gr |
             awk '{print $2}'); do
```

[image]

Additionally, use backticks instead of dollar-parenthesis for command substitution — quotes inside backticks behave somewhat bizarrely, and it's easy to make a mistake there. Quoting inside dollar-parenthesis is intuitive.

Comment: Nice answer. I realize top is an inherently interactive program, but I'm still surprised it isn't better behaved in a pipeline.

Comment: @JohnKugelman It surprises me too - especially when i wasn't using it in interactive mode...

Comment: @will I thought you were using `top` to sort by CPU usage; if you aren't, you don't need to pipe through `sort` and `awk` (I was wrong to propose `cut` since the fields are not tab-separated).

Comment: Nope, just to get the pids. Found out about the `proc/pid/fd` recently, quite like the idea of having some kind of tool to view the file access history and memory/cpu usage history of each task i run. Is there any way of finding out the process hierarchy?

Comment: @will `pstree`, if you want a visual representation. If you want historical data, you'll have to do some logging: sampling at regular intervals will miss some short-lived stuff.

Comment: Small spikes aren't really much of a concern, so shouldn't be too problematic.

Answer (score -2):

try to use "cut" instead of "awk", something like this:

```
for pid in `top -n 1 -u will | grep -iP "(scatci|congen|denprop|swmol3|sword|swedmos|swtrmo)" | sed 's/  / /g' | cut -d ' ' -f2`; do echo /proc/$pid/fd | head -n 2 | tail -n 1; done
```

Comment: Why? What's the difference?

Comment: It does actually deal better with the situation of sometimes there is a space at the beginning of the `top` output line, but it does not fix the underlying problem.